# URL in Android SMS message truncated

Tags: android, url, sms

We are sending text messages with a URL in them to mobile devices.  Most people didn't seem to have a problem, except Android users.

Multiple messaging apps attempt to "linkify" what they see as a URL in the body of the message.

For no apparent reason, only the first portion of our URL is treated this way with a few characters at the end that are not included in the link.  They *are* shown and they *are* correct.

They are just not part of the link so when the user clicks on the link, only the linkified portion is used and the link fails.

I know iOS had lots of problems with currency symbols and key words as they attempted to turn SMS into banking.  This is not that.

Comment: NOTE:  Further testing shows this does not happen with all Android versions.

Comment: seems like you are mentioning question and answer in question only ... please remove answer part from question and write answer ...

Comment: I think it's more of a messaging app. the user installed on device.. i.e the messaging app may be showing message as single even though there are 2 segments .... but not sure but its possible ...

Comment: Actually happened on both messaging apps, the Verizon one and the standard issue  I checked both.

Answer (score 0):

Found what was happening.

All SMS messages are broken into "segments" when they are too long to fit in one SMS message, usually 160 characters or so.

What I discovered is that if the URL in the message falls across a segment break (in my case segment two to segment three) when the segments are reassembled on the phone, the part of the link falling into the next segment is not included when the message app "linkifies" the URL.  It simply appears as trailing text.

Can't answer which OS version this is since it belonged to an end user.  The phone was a Galaxy S8+.  I did have the user update to the latest version available and the problem still existed.  I also had the user try two different messaging apps with the same result.

In the end, I simply changed the message text to always have the complete URL fall into a single message segment.  That's a half assed solution, but the only one available.  Time to move on.

I got lucky on this one with some screen shots, a bit of digging and an old man's intuition.

Here's a link to the Twilio segment calculator.  Thank God for those heroes.

[Twilio Message Segment Calculator](https://twiliodeved.github.io/message-segment-calculator/)

HTH someone.